# Can I get an explanation about why Quaternion.identity has a capital Q but transform.position is lower case t?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, terminology

Can I get an explanation about why Quaternion.identity has a capital Q but transform.position is lower case T? Is it because they are using a different directive or an assembly?

```
private void Fire() 
 {

    GameObject enemyLaser = Instantiate
    (enemyLaserPrefab, transform.position,
    Quaternion.identity)
    as GameObject;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) refers to a **type** since [`idendity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html) is `static` while [`transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-transform.html) refers to an **instance** property of type [`Transform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html) attached to the same `GameObject` as the script.

For some reason Unity uses camelCase notation for properties. Usually you would actually use PascalCase for `public` properties but those are "conventions" and basically you can decide to use other notations - at least they kept it mostly consistent.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Unity3d naming convention. The type, `Quaternion`, is capitalized. But they use "camel case" for properties and fields. Hence the uncapitalized `identity`.

It's completely arbitrary, but it is consistent throughout the Unity3d API.

Note that because `identity` is a static member, it is accessed via the type in which it's declared (`Quaternion`). The other members you're looking at, `transform` and `position` are both members of the current class. The `transform` property returns the transformation object for the current object, and the `position` property returns the position object for the transformation object. Because they are both class members, rather than type names, they are also camel-cased.

Comment: So transform comes from the Visual Studios naming convention under using system.generics?

Comment: @GodBleach: no, it's just a member of the current object. Indeed, none of the Microsoft naming convention would lead to any public member being camel-case, never mind a type name being camel-case. The .NET naming convention uses Pascal-case through all public members (part of that convention also generally rules out public fields, but occasionally an exception is made for read-only fields...those still will have Pascal-case names though)

Comment: so, for example, identity is a sub class of GameObject so it's not capitalise becuase it's being used like a variable instead of a type?

Comment: No, `identity` is not a "subclass". A subclass would be a type that inherits another type. `identity` is a property of the `Quaternion` type. It's a _member_, not an inheriting type. And it's not capitalized, because it's not a type. The naming has nothing to do with how something is _used_. It is based on what that thing _is_. (Granted, what it is directly leads to determining how it's used, but you don't get to choose that...it's forced on you by the language.)

Comment: ok I see, is identity only a member to Quaternion or can it be a member to other types?

Comment: Any other type could declare a member `identity`. And indeed, some types may (like a matrix type). But note that it would be **a completely different member**. In spite of having the same name, it would not in any way refer to the same thing. That's why it has to be qualified with the type name when you use it (or in the case of non-static members, qualified with an object reference, or the implicit `this` reference)

Comment: Please note: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. Your comments lead me to believe that you would be much better served by taking some time to track down and read some introductory web sites, documentation, etc. that explain basic C# concepts to programmers new to the language. The comments section isn't an appropriate place to carry on a conversation, so I will have to leave this discussion here where it stands.